# this is heuristically generated and may not be correct

Tags: vcpkg

When I use the vcpkg install command , in manifest mode , to install LIBZIP and CURL like this :

vcpkg install --triplet x64-windows

I get this error :

libzip provides CMake targets:

```
# this is heuristically generated, and may not be correct
find_package(libzip CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE libzip::zip)
```

curl provides CMake targets:

```
# this is heuristically generated, and may not be correct
find_package(CURL CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE CURL::libcurl)
```

this is the VCPKG.JSON file content:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/vcpkg-tool/main/docs/vcpkg.schema.json",
  "builtin-baseline": "3426db05b996481ca31e95fff3734cf23e0f51bc",
  "dependencies": ["zlib","openssl","dirent","getopt","curl","libzip"]
  
}
```

openssl , zlib , getopt and dirent are installed without error for example:

The package openssl is compatible with built-in CMake targets:

```
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE OpenSSL::SSL OpenSSL::Crypto)
```

I am very stuck and do not know how to solve the error above . I have windows 10

Comment: What error? I only see a notice about `this is heuristically generated, and may not be correct`.

Comment: I thought "this is heuristically generated, and may not be correct" is an error . This notice implies that the installed package may function incorrectly and therefore it can produce other problems . Thus I would like to know how to ensure that the installed package is properly  built without that notice .

Comment: Always consult the documentation for the library that you are installing. Usually the vcpkg listed methods for `find_package()` and `target_link_libraries()` work as is, but each library vendor can customize the parameters. Some libraries, like `boost`, break their library into components. The boost `find_package()` has more options (components) that you specify. Example: `find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS date_time filesystem iostreams system thread timer)`. Therefore, always read the library's documentation on vcpkg and cmake.

Comment: Tip: For Windows, you will probably need to add `OpenSSL::applink` to `target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE OpenSSL::SSL OpenSSL::Crypto)`. Otherwise, the suggestion from vcpkg is correct.

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer does not help me . Not only  I am always used to read the documentation of every library , software that i download or install but also I do my searches about every error or notice I get . Unfortunately , there are very few sources about the notice above . The ones I found are in github but could not help me solve the notice above . I still do not know  how can a package be installed ,with  vcpkg, and built properly and correctly without getting the above notice . Do you know how ?

Comment: You do **NOT** need to solve that error nor can you solve it. It is a notice from `vcpkg` and is not an error. The message is telling you that it does not know the correct format and is indirectly recommending that you look it up in the library documentation.